# javax mail getReceivedDate in sender's time zone

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I want to get the received date in email sender's timezone. is that possible with javax mail ?
The `message.getReceivedDate()` returns date in my server's timezone.

Comment: If you were able to send the mail alongside an extra packet of data, which would contain the senders EST, that would be an immediate fix. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: When user sends a mail I process it and reply the user with success. I want to also include the timestamp in reply when the original mail was sent

Comment: So would it be possible to send any extra data alongside the e-mail; are you using your own SMTP?

Comment: No. user will send the mail from his client.

Comment: Do you have a server taking in the data and then sending it to the appropriate people? If not you could add the Date and Time to the bottom of every E-Mail and then you could process it according to what time you received it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I know, and at least in Java 7, the `Date` class has (by itsel) no notion of an original time zone. So if you want to have access to the original time zone of a mail, you should directly get the `Date` header : `message.getHeader("Date")`.

According to RFC2822, this header must allways be present, must contain a timezone, and should be expressed in local time. So you have to parse the value and extract the sender timezone. Next you only have to convert the `getReceivedDate` to that time zone.

Extracts from RFC2822 (for the parsing of Date header) :

```
orig-date       =       "Date:" date-time CRLF
date-time       =       [ day-of-week "," ] date FWS time [CFWS]
day-of-week     =       ([FWS] day-name) / obs-day-of-week
day-name        =       "Mon" / "Tue" / "Wed" / "Thu" /
                        "Fri" / "Sat" / "Sun"
date            =       day month year
year            =       4*DIGIT / obs-year
month           =       (FWS month-name FWS) / obs-month
month-name      =       "Jan" / "Feb" / "Mar" / "Apr" /
                        "May" / "Jun" / "Jul" / "Aug" /
                        "Sep" / "Oct" / "Nov" / "Dec"
day             =       ([FWS] 1*2DIGIT) / obs-day
time            =       time-of-day FWS zone
time-of-day     =       hour ":" minute [ ":" second ]
hour            =       2DIGIT / obs-hour
minute          =       2DIGIT / obs-minute
second          =       2DIGIT / obs-second
zone            =       (( "+" / "-" ) 4DIGIT) / obs-zone
```